# Replace Lato Font with roboto

Tags: html, css, fonts

In my Web application  I am using google font 'Lato'.Now Requirement is I should use 'Roboto' font for my web application.

I replace Lato font with Roboto but This reflect major change in terms of spacing in whole Web application.
Where I am doing mistake?

I cant share whole page screenshot.

Original with Lato
[image: This is my original part]

Disturb with Roboto
[image]

Comment: you are not doing mistake lato and roboto are two different fonts its natural that you will se some changes after changing the whole application font..

Comment: @GauravAggarwal, so big changes that you go and ask a question? Not seems realistic. I expect there to be problems really.

Comment: can you share screen with both the fonts..lets check what kind of problems you are facing

Comment: @Gaurav I cant share more info about my web application.Thank you.Please refer above screen.

Answer (score 1):

Every font-family have own letter spacing and line-height. Now you need yo set re-structure your letter spacing and line-height!

Answer (score 0):

Definitely in specifiing sizes for elements. If you need to translate the site to other language, you meet the same problems. If you change some text you have the same problems. And so on.

Everyting depending on text should not have explicit sizes (width at least). So when you change te text or the font, element just enlarges or shrinks without negative effect in most cases.

The only exception is placing some set of elements inside of one raw or limiting their max-width. These can cause problems if more text appears or new font is wider. Anyway, it's not good if the whole site consists of such elements. And Roboto is not wider than Lato, so it's not your case.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to view your webpage ?

You can also change the spacing between letters using the css property "letter-spacing"

```css
h1 {
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
h2 {
  letter-spacing: 5px;
}
```

```html
<h1>SAMPLE</h1>
<h2>SAMPLE</h2>
```

Comment: Letter spacing is better in em.